# How to create multiple dock widget in tab format in QDockWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt, qt5, qgraphicsview

I have created QDockWidget which has tool bar with icons and view from QGraphicsView. Now I want to create multiple dock widget in tab form.
Here is the code

```
addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea,sView);

QDockWidget* dockWidget1 = new QDockWidget("SView1") ;

addDockWidget(Qt::BottomDockWidgetArea ,  dockWidget1 );

tabifyDockWidget(sView,dockWidget1);      

connect(dockWidget1,SIGNAL(visibilityChanged(true)), this,SLOT(new myView("SView1")));
```

I am able to see 2 dock widget ( SView and SView1). 1st dock widget showing all the necessary layouts ( tool bar , icons etc ) but 2nd one is blank.
So I tried to use signals and slots so that, when I will click on 2nd  dock widget (which is in 2nd tab ) I will call class myView's constructor. All the layouts like tool bar , icons are created in class myView's constructor's. But nothing is happening. My 2nd dock widget is still blank.
So I am trying to achieve

> 1. My 2nd dock widget should get all the layout of 1st dock widget.
> 2. If I want to create "n" number of dock widget ( but don't want to
>    show initially and it will be visible and invisible as and when needed
>    ) How to create them ?

How to achieve these features ?

Now I am getting message as

> QObject::connect: No such signal QDockWidget::visibilityChanged(true)

Comment: What is exactly your problem? Creating two `QDockWidget`'s that are tabified on each other? Or showing some content inside a `QDockWidget`? Have you tried calling `QDockWidget::setWidget`? Maybe a screenshot may help to clarify your issue.

Comment: @m7913d : I have added screenshot. Please take a look.

Comment: @m7913d I want to show all the contents from 1st dock widget like tool bar, icons everything into 2nd dock widget, once I clicked on it.

Comment: Does calling `QDockWidget::setWidget` inside your slot solve the issue?

Comment: @m7913d No,  problem is still there.  After setting the widget , I did `show()`.  And now I am getting message as `QObject::connect: No such signal QDockWidget::visibilityChanged(true)`